# Remove "URL:" from bibliography, but not the actual url

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, urls

I want to include URLs in the bibliography, but I don't want the text `URL:` to be in the bibliography.

I understand I can use `note = {\url{...}}` but is there a way to achieve this without modifying the `.bib` file?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-ibid]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
 @misc{knuth1968art,
  title={The Art of Computer Programming 1: Fundamental Algorithms 2: Seminumerical Algorithms 3: Sorting and Searching},
  author={Knuth, D},
  year={1968},
  publisher={MA: Addison-Wesley},
  url={http://google.com}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
 \nocite{knuth1968art}
 \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: That should be as easy as `\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can display the URL on its own with

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\url{#1}}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The previous label is still there. How can I remove it?

Comment: @EmeraJade This works for the standard styles. If it does not work for you, the label you see must be generated by something else. It's hard to say what is responsible without knowing what is going on on your side, so please ask a new question with an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that shows the style you use and the modifications you already applied.

Comment: That already solved it, I took a look at the .blx of german-apa and figured it out. Thanks for your hint! :)